# So I'm trying to install build tools and dependencies , and when I execute I get

Tags: software-installation

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts debhelper autoconf build-essential dpkg-dev gengetopt libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-ddp ev libtool
Reading package lists...Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information...Done
E: Unable to locate package libssl-ddp
E: Unable to locate package evlibtool
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What instructions are you following?

Comment: No such package `libssl-ddp` or `ev` exists in the Ubuntu repositories. Re-read your instructions - you missed a step. You also made a typo: `ev` and `libtool` are separate packages and must be separated by a space. We gently recommend you double-check your own work before bringing it to us.

Comment: Don't just copy commands names from some random page in the internet and then post a question here. At least search packages.ubuntu.com first...

Comment: I suspect that "libssl-ddp ev" was supposed to be `libssl-dev` & the dp is nonsense from something or other..

Answer (score 2):

On 14.04 or 16.04 use this

`sudo apt-get install devscripts debhelper autoconf build-essential dpkg-dev gengetopt libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev libtool`